# IIS 7 "account that is running application pool"

Tags: iis-7

I need to find out which account is running one of my websites application pool.
I need to add the user to a database in SQL Server.
Using IIS Manager, is there a way to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Identity" column in the Application Pool area of IIS is the account.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running asp.net a quick and dirty way is a helper aspx page like so:

```
<%@Page %>

IIS is running as : 
  <%=System.Security.:Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name%>
```